# Are we able Execute INSERT STATEMENT inside hibernate CreateSQLQUERY

Tags: hibernate

I have two keys for

```
class A {
    @Id
    long key1;
    @Id
    long key2;
}
```

and I want to insert them (I am intentionality not using embeddedId )
how can I do it ?
What is the syntax inside `createSQLQuery` if exist one? Is there a way to insert using hql ?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, check this:

- [Using a SQLQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-creating)
- [createQuery examples](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/)